# addSubview not showing up in NSView Objective C Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

When I `addSubview:` nothing shows up. I set text and color to see it. Also if I manually add the view to the custom view in the UI bulder in xcode it shows up just fine with the text and color.

.m file

```
- (void)displayString:(NSString *)title {
    NSRect frame = NSMakeRect(10, 10, 200, 17);
    NSTextfield *newfield = [[NSTextField alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    [newfield setBezeled:NO];
    [newfield setDrawsBackground:NO];
    [newfield setEditable:NO];
    [newfield setSelectable:NO];
    [newfield setStringValue:title];
    [newfield setTextColor:[NSColor blueColor]];
    [test addSubview:newfield];

    if([test.subviews containsObject:newfield]){
        NSLog(@"view there"); // i get this message 
    }
    if([newfield isHidden]){
        NSLog(@"view hidden"); //i dont get this message
    }
    NSLog(@"view set");

}
```

`test` is a `NSView` (Custom view is what xcode calls it) that I have properly linked in.

So when I create the text field and add it to the `NSView` manually and then run that same code by adding text and color all works fine, this issue arrises when I try programmatically setting the view. Also I made sure it wasn't my creating of the view, as I have tried creating the view in the builder and not placing it in the `NSView` and then trying `addSubview:` but that also does not work. Let me know if you need more code.

DEVELOPMENT:
If the nsview (custom view) has an element already in it (manually added and can be anything) and I add the text field it works (I get both views in the nsview)? The subview is tested for and there, just cant see it. 
[image]

Comment: I think your NSTextField has no dimensions and that's why it's not showing up. Try setting the frame or bounds, or call `initWithFrame:bundle:` instead of the regular init and see what that gives.

Comment: Ok so I gave that a shot and no change. I didn't think it would have resulted in a change because when I created the text field in the xcode builder and then tried to add it, I had the same issue. Only way it works is if both `NSView` and the textfield are pre made and pre located.

Comment: Have you tried to bring the subview to the front? (self.view bringSubviewToFront:newfield])

Comment: I get no visible @interface for 'nsview' declairs the selector 'bringsubviewtofront:' when I do `[test bringSubviewToFront:newfield];`

Comment: Elaborate on your newest edit.  You can't see it?  Does that mean it's hidden (You can test that by `isHidden`), or is it beyond the frame of the superview?

Comment: Nothing seems to be hidden, and I dont think its beyond the superview because when I put any random view (label version of textfield lets say) in the xcode ui builder in the custom view, my addsubview works (I see both views, manually added label and my textfield)

Comment: @Mr.SirKingOsman Just to be sure, print out the frame of the text field, and if none works, try put a hidden label so that the user can't see it, but you'll be able to add the text field.

Comment: Sorry I am a litte confused what do you mean print out the frame?

Comment: I think what he meant is the same i'm about to suggest you do: NSLog the frame's x, y, width and height, both for the text field and the parent you're adding it to. Provide those results and then we can go from there. Oh and maybe you could try to set the background of the parent NSView (without adding to label) to see if the view itself is properly displayed? Maybe you need to set the bounds or frame of the NSView itself (cause maybe it's 0,0,0,0 because it contains nothing and you don't have it set to auto resize to its parent).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to call `initWithFrame:` instead of just `init`

```
- (void)displayString:(NSString *)title {
    NSRect frame = NSMakeRect(10, 10, 200, 200);
    NSTextField *newfield = [[NSTextField alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    [newfield setStringValue:title];
    [newfield setTextColor:[NSColor blueColor]];
    [test addSubview:newfield];
    NSLog(@"view set");
}
```

Comment: thats not the issue, I tried that and still. I added a new hint in my question at the bottom of my question.

Comment: I had the same problem with an `NSViewImage` and I was just calling `alloc` without `initWithFrame`. After adding it the view appeared.

Answer (score 1):

What type of view is test? Also you need to do a:

```
 newfield.frame = CGRectMake(x,y,width,height)
```

in order to specify the look of the view

Comment: interesting development, if the nsview (custom view) has an element already in it (manually added) and I add the text field it works?

Comment: You can double check that it's actually being added by using         if([test.subviews containsObject:newfield])

Comment: so that if statement is not firing.... what would keep it from being added, there seems to be a step im missing in preparing the custom view to take on subviews.

Comment: big mistake, in rushing to address everyone i put the if statement before the `addSubview`, but once I put it in the right place, ya its there, just not visible.

Comment: Have you specified the frame prior to adding it to the view?

Comment: the subview? If so yes I will update my question to reflect what I currently have

Comment: Yeah the frame of the subview. update your code and then we can talk

Comment: Two questions: Why are you using a textfield if you aren't allowing the user to edit it? (maybe a label would be more appropriate?) Second, I think you might need to be using a CGRect instead of and NSRect... just set it like 'initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,width,height)'

Comment: The first part, I just went from a text field to label and the other part I had that before but one of the answers said to use that instead, ill change it back but that was not the issue.

Comment: It the one part of the xcode element list. It says Custom View- provides you with an instance of a view subclass that is not available  in interface builder.

Comment: So do you have a class that extends UIView and then you add that UIView to some viewController that you have implemented in interface builder? Because you need to be aware that the subview is dependent upon the origin of the view that you're adding it to (not the origin of the viewController as a whole)

Comment: Yes xcode builder (if im not mistaken) creates the class that extends view class and I have `@property (weak) IBOutlet NSView *test;` in my .h file. I added a helpful diagram that might help to my question.

Comment: So my question is what does xcode add to my custom view code wise when I put something inside of it? You see what i mean?

Comment: No, you need to specify and create the class associated with things you create in interface builder (except for the very first viewController created in a project)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I set the view too early. I was under the impression that whatever you do to the view after its been set will be reflected on the view, but that seemed to be the issue. After altering the view to be exactly they way I want then set the view of the `NSStatuditem`. 
 so I get

```
  [newfield setStringValue:title];
  [newfield setTextColor:[NSColor blueColor]];
  [test addSubview:newfield];
  [statusItem setView:test];//this is the key, setting it after he changes.
```